# How to implement c++ mysql blob column

Tags: c++, mysql

So the question is how do I create a table with a blob column then populate it with 
an int array. i.e

```
int myblob[128];

mysql_query(con, "CREATE TABLE list(Id INT, type blob)"); // blob?
mysql_query(con, "INSERT into table list values(1, myblob)"); // what is the syntax?
```

The example above shows me creating the table with a blob field (With the incorrect syntax)
and then inserting my blob into the table. (with the incorrect syntax)

What is the correct syntax for this statement?

Comment: What all have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to begin...